# Keep getting Type error

Tags: python-2.7

I tried to run the following codes, and I keep getting the errors as below. When I delete re.sub(r'/n','') I get the same error for the next one (&$[^\s]. I know that is due to regular expression, but I have no idea what is wrong. Please help me. I spent the whole night to figure this out. The input is a list of strings and that is returned from find_sentences(text):

```
def find_sentences(text):
    k = re.compile(r'[^\.]*\.[^\.]*succession[^\.]*\.[^\.]*\.')
    k2 = k.findall(text)
    if len(k2)>1:
        k3 = '######################################'.join(str(i) for i in k2)
    else:
        k3 = k2
    return k3 

q1=find_sentences(replacement)  #replacement is a text.
q2 = re.sub(r'\n','', q1)
q3 = re.sub(r'&#[^\s]+;','', q2)
q4 = re.sub(r'&nbsp;','', q3)
q5 = re.sub(r'\\','',q4)
sentence = re.sub(r'<[^>]+>','',q5)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahn\Desktop\text_module ver 1.py", line 135, in <module>
    dataValues=do_combination(fullPath)
  File "C:\Users\Ahn\Desktop\text_module ver 1.py", line 100, in do_combination
    q2 = re.sub(r'\n','', q1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: have you tried using a line break in the debugger to check that q1 has a valid type at the line in question?

Comment: Jared, how to check it? sorry, I am a beginner. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on how you're running your code but if you are using an IDE that lets you run code and set a line break your execution will stop at that line and you can check the variable values. If you don't know how to use a debugger, stop writing code until you do. It will save you a measurably large chunk of time and an immeasurably large number of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

The `findall` function returns a *list* of strings. The key point is that it *always* returns a list, so I'm not sure what the point of your `len(k2)>1` test is.

The problem is likely that `k2` is a single-element list (which is different from just a string). It looks like you could change your code to the following and it might do what you want:

```
k2 = k.findall(text)
k3 = '######################################'.join(k2)
return k3
```

However, it's not clear exactly what you want so you will have to experiment.

Comment: I need len(k2)>1 because the findall returns one item for some texts, but returns more than one item for others. In the latter case, I tried to make two items as one string split by ##########.

Comment: Yes, but in the case where `findall` returns one element, the `join` won't add a separator because there is only one element. The smallest change to your existing code that might make it work would be to change `k3 = k2` to `k3 = k2[0]`.

Comment: removing str() fixes the problem. Thanks, guys.